# ng-bootstrap - Container properties on Modal Component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap

On ng-bootstrap site, `Modal component` -> `Api` there is an information that modal has  properties `conatainer` with descriprion: "`An element to which to attach newly opened modal windows`". Does it mean that I can attach opened modal directly to specified div id element on my HTML site?

If so, how to acheive that on Angular project? 
In my project I added in my modal-basic.html this code:

```
<div id="test" class="col-6">Some text</div>
```

And added properties container also:

```
this.modalService.open(content, {container: 'test',ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {

  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
```

But I'm receiving an error:

```
NgbdModalBasic.html:28 ERROR Error: The specified modal container "test" was not found in the DOM.
    at NgbModalStack.push../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js.NgbModalStack.open (ng-bootstrap.js:6417)
    at NgbModal.push../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/fesm5/ng-bootstrap.js.NgbModal.open (ng-bootstrap.js:6681)
    at NgbdModalBasic.push../src/app/modal-basic.ts.NgbdModalBasic.open (modal-basic.ts:16)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (NgbdModalBasic.html:28)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10258)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11054)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:7717)
    at core.js:8161
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:995)
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying the container element you need to pass in either the element or a selector or a combination of both. In your case you want to reach elements with an ID of test. The container property should be set to "#test'.

```
this.modalService.open(content, {container: '#test',ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
  this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
}, (reason) => {

  this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Right now modal is showing but always in the same place. It is not attached to element. I took example code from this site: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: I created this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggcvsl, if you inspect the div with id of test when the modal is opened the modal appears inside it.

Comment: Ok I see. One more question. How to manipulate this modal to show them directly in the container element? For example on the left side of 'test' element?

Comment: Rather use a popover for that I believe you can use a template for the popover content. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#tplcontent

The problem with using a modal in this way is that its not designed to be beside an element. So you would have to edit the CSS in such a way that it display next to the desired element.